# Is this integration correct?

Tags: integration

I am checking some papers.

$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{D_{ab}}{2k^2}} \left( v_{ab} \left( {t_n - \frac{D_{ab}}{2k^2} }\right)^2 + d_m \right)^\frac{\alpha}{2} dt_n\\
$$
and
$$
d_m^{\frac\alpha2}\cdot\left(\frac{D_{ab}}{2k^2}\right)
\left\{ \frac{{i(k)}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\alpha+1} + 
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\frac{{i(k)}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-1}}{\alpha-1} +
\frac{\alpha-2}{\alpha-1}
\frac{{i(k)}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-2}}{\alpha-3} +\cdots
\right\}
$$

where
$$
i(k)=\frac{v_{ab}}{d_m}\cdot{\frac{D_{ab}}{2k^2}}^2+1
$$

are same?

The paper said "using integration by substitution."

Comment: A key tool is the expansion of $(1+x)^{a/2}$, applied to $x=\frac{v_{ab}}{d_m}\cdot \left( {t_n - \frac{D_{ab}}{2k^2} }\right)^2$. Can you write it down?

Comment: I will try with that $x$. Thank you